# NodeJS(SocketIO) authentication token

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sockets, socket.io

I am developing a application of two-way communication in SocketIO between App of iPhone and server.

I would like to implement the authentication function when connecting from the application side to the chat server.

I have implemented on the server side as described below.

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {

    var token = handshakeData.query.token;

    checkAuthToken(token, callback);

});
```

However, I do not know where I should set the token in the app side.

```
var socket:SIOSocket! = nil

SIOSocket.socketWithHost("ServerUrl" , response: { (_socket: SIOSocket!) in
    self.socket = _socket

    println(self.socket)

    self.socket.onConnect = {() in
       println("connected")

    }
})
```

To borrow your wisdom.

(Server-side)     · NodeJS (v0.10.26)           - Socket.io@1.3.6

(Client side)     · Swift1.6          - SIOSocket     · Xcode6.4

Comment: Or.Ron, Thank you for setting swift tag.